# WebMatrix error when using FTP?

Tags: iis, windows-8, webmatrix

When I use WebMatrix (the latest version, on Windows 8 RP) to try to connect to an FTP site, it shows an error where files should be shown. I actually have no idea what could be causing this, and I can't find any log file that could help. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t4Lb.jpg

I'm also using IIS 8 to host a local PHP/MySQL site, if that matters

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: This generally happens when your network connection drops.  Are you able to connect to the ftp site using another client (FileZilla)?

Comment: @JustinBeckwith - yes, it works fine with FTP in Explorer (just opening a new explorer window and typing the server name and entering in the credentials. Also, I've tried it on multiple wifi networks, so it doesn't seem to be related to the network. Do you know if there's a log file that could help tell me what the specific error was?

Comment: Yikes.  We don't have a log for FTP right now (we're adding it soon).  However, you can get more details if you go to the Remote Tab, click on settings, and then click on 'Validate'.  Could you give us the results of that?

Comment: yes, it does work (it says "connected successfully").

Comment: also, it seems that it correctly lists the files for my website, but somehow it only gets an error when looking into public_html - http://imgur.com/W0FhT public_html contains a lot of files, maybe there's some limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might actually be a different issue.  There is a bug in WebMatrix RC that causes the remote view to behave badly when connecting to directories with large numbers of files.

We've fixed this now, and it should not repro in our next release.  Sorry for any inconveniences this has caused.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it turned out to be because I had a file called "CFLogo.png" and another file called "cflogo.png" on my server and WebMatrix wasn't able to deal with both of them having essentially the same name :\